# Compare Object Array to Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Object Array containing conditions and i am trying to search or compare the object array against values in a simple array:

```
var myObjArr = [ {this: "someval", that: "anotherval" }, {this: "someval", that: "anotherval" }, {this: "someval", that: "anotherval" } ];
```

Then I have a results array...

```
var newArrResults = [ "anotherval", "someval", "anotherval2" ];
```

I need to check myObjArr for any of the string values in the results array newArrResults. I've tried it many ways and most ways are unstable.

What i tried:

```
for(var b = 0; b<myObjArr.length; b++){
    if(newArrResults.indexOf(myObjArr[b].this) !== -1 && newArrResults.indexOf(myObjArr[b].that) !== -1 ) {
   // is unstable
   // i need to know if there are exact matches in "this & that"
}
```

The first way I tried was looping through the ArrayObject and looking for indexOf but this seems to be a bit unstable. Any thoughts? Help? Ideas to lead me in the right direction?

Comment: What is unstable?

Comment: You should change the variable name `this` in your object array. `this` in Javascript is a keyword and has a specific meaning

Comment: What data types are stored in the objects and in the newArrResults array?

Comment: Please provide an example when your code fails and what result you expect then

Comment: I don't need the objArray to display in the exact order... it seems to be looking for them in order that is why it's failing I believe @AnthonyCollins

Comment: @AnthonyCollins it only seems to work if in that order. Perhaps this is what I am setting up when searching using indexOf?

Answer (score 0):

```
 let found =  myObjArr.filter((item)=>{
     return newArrResults.indexOf(item.this) > - 1 ||newArrResults.indexOf(item.that) > -1;
}).length > 0
```

'found' will be a boolean that tells you if it's in the array.

Comment: im not getting a single result from this... the output of my newArrResult is a typical array - i verified it via the console it looks like ["this","new","that"]

Comment: I ran this with your example code and it works.  What do you want for a result?  It's true/false like it seems like you want.  console.log(found) will tell you if it's found or not.

Comment: What I need is for the objArray to find the string items in any combination. It seems to only be checking for them in order.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in your code -
 1. You should avoid using reserved keywords of the language like `this`
 2. A closing curly bracket '}' was missing in your `for` loop

The following code works for what you want -

```
var myObjArr = [ {foo: "someval", bar: "anotherval" }, {foo: "someval", bar: "anotherval" }, {foo: "someval", bar: "anotherval" }, {foo:"someVal",bar:"noVal"}];

var newArrResults = [ "anotherval", "someval", "anotherval2" ];

for(var b = 0; b<myObjArr.length; b++){
    if(newArrResults.indexOf(myObjArr[b].foo) !== -1 &&
       newArrResults.indexOf(myObjArr[b].bar) !== -1 ) {
    console.log("Exact match");
   //exact matches in "foo & bar"
   }
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qq38124/)

Comment: this doesnt work... the script just sticks when i change it to !== instead of !=

Comment: What do you mean by `sticks`? Could you pinpoint in the Fiddle link provided?

Comment: my code looks exactly like what you have in the fiddle and it doesnt work... i tried to run it and it does nothing...

Comment: Did you add the missing curly bracket to your code? And changed the variable name from `this` to something else?